# Relationship eigenvalues of $X'X$ and $(X'X)^{-1}$

Tags: regression, least-squares

I've a question regarding to eigenvalues, sinve I am not very familiar with the concept.
Suppose I've a matrix $X'X$ in the case of an OLS regession. And lets assume that the regarding eigenvalues are very small. This imlpies strongly multicollinearity and a high variance of the OLS estimators. 
Is there any relationship between the eigenvalues of  $X'X$ and the ones of  $(X'X)^{-1}$ ?

The following point should be correct: The smaller the eigenvalues of $X'X$ or the larger the eigenvalues of $(X'X)^{-1}$ the nearer we are to multicollinearity and $Var(\beta)$ will be large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say $\lambda$ is one of the eigen values of $X'X$.

For eiegen vector $v$, this equation is hold : $X'X v= \lambda v$

And this can be rewritten like this : $(X'X)^{-1} v= \lambda^{-1} v$

which implies that the eiegen values of the inverse matrix is reciprocal of those of the original matrix.

I hope this is helpful for you.

I am not a native  English speaker.
Any improvement is welcome.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you. This would underline my last sentence. And the larger the eigenvalues of the inverse are the large the variance of the coefficients, or am I wrong ?

Comment: How about using spectral decomposition? That allows us to write like this : $(X'X)^{-1}=A' \Lambda A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_i v_i'$

Comment: and the variance covariance matrix of beta vector is $\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}$

Comment: I think this would show that your statement is true clearly.

Comment: I am not familiar with specral decomposition, still a beginner in statistics^^. But it seems as larger the the eigenvalues of the inverse as larger the variance, via spectral decompositoin

Comment: Don't mention it.

Comment: This answer skips a crucial step that will reveal it is not always correct: it implicitly assumes $\lambda$ is nonzero.  Indeed, the eigenvalue equation cannot be rewritten as claimed unless $\lambda\ne 0.$

Comment: @whuber I thought that because question has assumed the matrix is not singular so it's full rank which means no eigen values of it are zero

Comment: Since the problem concerns the case of "very small" eigenvalues we need to tread carefully.  A more perspicuous analysis notes that if $X^\prime X$ has a generalized inverse $(X^\prime X)^{-}$, then premultiplication of the original equation on the left by the generalized inverse yields $v = \lambda (X^\prime X)^{-} v.$

Comment: That's the point I couldn't make out. Thank you for more elaboration. I didn't learn analysis and I am studying math all by myself. I guess I am very prone to be careless and miss some important points as you noticed. Thanks again!